# ZeroMQ - N-to-N server communication for a consensus negotiation

Tags: python, concurrency, zeromq

I am implementing a consensus algorithm ([raft](https://raft.github.io/)) where 5 servers have to communicate together asynchronously to manage a replicated log. 
I am using python and `multiprocessing` package to run 5 processes acting as servers, and ØMQ (pyzmq) to handle communications between servers.

I drafted a first design and I am wondering about a few things:

I have 5 servers, and I hardcode 5 "identities" I configure sockets with. For each server, I am using two `ROUTER` sockets:

- the first one is binding to the server's identity (this socket is responsible for receiving others messages)
- the other one is connecting to the other servers' identities (this one is responsible for sending messages)

It looks strange to me to use two `ROUTER` sockets on the same node/server, but I do not find better : is there a more elegant way to proceed?

I tried to use only one `ROUTER` socket per server, i.e a socket that sets its identity, binds on its given port, and connects to the others, but this 'connect' step on each side doesn't work : what is the reason for that?

Here is a simple example with 3 servers:

```
import time
from threading import Thread
from typing import List

import zmq

SEND_RULE = {
    '5555': '6666',
    '6666': '7777',
    '7777': '5555'
}

def worker(socket_port: str, peer_ports: List[str]):
    context = zmq.Context()

    receiving_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    receiving_socket.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, socket_port.encode())
    receiving_socket.bind(f'tcp://*:{socket_port}')

    sending_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    sending_socket.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, socket_port.encode())

    for peer_port in peer_ports:
        sending_socket.connect(f'tcp://localhost:{peer_port}')

    time.sleep(1)

    recipient_id = SEND_RULE[socket_port].encode()
    message_for_recipient = b'coucou!'

    print(socket_port, ' sending a message to ', recipient_id.decode())
    sending_socket.send_multipart([recipient_id, message_for_recipient])

    # Receive a message from peer
    sender_id, sender_message = receiving_socket.recv_multipart()

    print( socket_port,
         ' server received: ',
           sender_message.decode(),
         ' from: ',
           sender_id.decode()
           )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket_ports = ['5555', '6666', '7777']
    for socket_port in socket_ports:
        Thread( target = worker,
                args   = ( socket_port,
                           [ port for port in socket_ports
                                   if port != socket_ports ]
                           )
                ).start()

    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: And the MCVE-code is where?

Comment: Rudely asked, but here it is!

Comment: StackOverflow strongly discourages Community Members from not following the Community Rules & Best Practices - one of which is not to present an MCVE-code formulation of the problem a Member is asking the Community to sponsor a help with. Posting a Question without any MCVE-code formulated problem is both meaningless w.r.t. the subject and arrogant w.r.t. the Community Ethics. **Feel free to violate the Community Rules as much as you wish**, yet the only results achieved by doing so are going sort of against initial your wish to receive from us a sponsored help with your problem, aren't they?

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask : "Not all questions benefit from including code."
I sincerely considered my description contained enough information, but I can, of course, hear that it needs more details : asking a nice way seems sensible then.

Thank you for your edit.